# When i transcribed code it appeared white screen

Tags: html, css

I try to copy this code in new pen or in index file https://codepen.io/alexerlandsson/pen/JKyqky but show up white screen ( example : http s://codepen.io/GARDFIELD3/pen/WpqYdW ) (cut the space) 
Photo with white screen : [whitescreen..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne1bL.png)
Please help me to give me a solution to when copying code in new pen or site index file look the same ..

***code for first link codepen ( the good / original )**

**html**

```
<div data-am-fadeshow="next-prev-navigation autoplay">

    <!-- Radio -->
    <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-1" />
    <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-2" />
    <input type="radio" name="css-fadeshow" id="slide-3" />

    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="fs-slides">
        <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460500063983-994d4c27756c?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1325&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=2550);">
            <!-- Add content to images (sample) -->
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: white; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center; text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                <h1 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.8vw; font-size: 5vw; font-weight: bold;">Pure CSS Fadeshow</h1>
                <p style="font-size: 2vw; font-weight: 100; margin-top: 0;">Easy to implement and use on <strong>your</strong> site!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440557653082-e8e186733eeb?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1325&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=2500);"></div>
        <div class="fs-slide" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449057528837-7ca097b3520c?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1325&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=2500);"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Quick Navigation -->
    <div class="fs-quick-nav">
        <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
        <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
        <label class="fs-quick-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
    </div>

    <!-- Prev Navigation -->
    <div class="fs-prev-nav">
        <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
        <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
        <label class="fs-prev-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
    </div>

    <!-- Next Navigation -->
    <div class="fs-next-nav">
        <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-1"></label>
        <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-2"></label>
        <label class="fs-next-btn" for="slide-3"></label>
    </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
/*
 * CSS Fadeshow by @alexerlandsson
 * This is a fadeshow built in CSS and with customization in focus.
 * Supports quick navigation, prev/next navigation and autoplay.
 * 
 * For better documentation and implementation guide, check out the GitHub repository:
 * https://github.com/alexerlandsson/css-fadeshow
*/


/*
 * ===== VARIABLES =====
 *
 * Change these variables to match your preferences. For a more detailed
 * description of what each variable do, visit https://github.com/alexerlandsson/css-fadeshow
 */

$max-slides:                    5;
$prefix:                            true;
$responsive:                    true;
$breakpoint-small:          500px;
$fade-time:                     1;
$prev-next-fontfamily:      sans-serif;
$prev-next-icon-size:       3vw;
$prev-next-icon-color:      rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
$prev-next-bg:                  rgba(255,255,255,0);
$prev-next-bg-hover:            rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
$prev-icon:                     '❮';
$next-icon:                     '❯';
$autohide-next-prev:            true;
$quick-nav-color:               rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
$quick-nav-active-color:    coral;
$fade-color:                    #fff;
$autoplay:                      true;
$autoplay-duration:         3;


/*
 * ===== MIXINS =====
 *
 * This section contains mixin used
 * Do not change anything here unless you know what you are doing.
 */

/* Mixins to handle prefixes */

@mixin fadeshow-transition($value...) {
    @if length($value) < 1 {
        $value: all 150ms linear;
    }
    @if $prefix == true {
        -webkit-transition: $value;
    }
                  transition: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-transform($value...) {
    @if length($value) < 1 {
        $value: all 150ms linear;
    }
    @if $prefix == true {
        -webkit-transform: $value;
             -ms-transform: $value;
    }
                  transform: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-animation($value...) {
    @if $prefix == true {
        -webkit-animation: $value;
    }
                  animation: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-animation-delay($value) {
    @if $prefix == true {
        -webkit-animation-delay: $value;
    }
                  animation-delay: $value;
}

@mixin fadeshow-unselectable() {
    @if $prefix == true {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
             -ms-user-select: none;
    }
                  user-select: none;
}

/* Mixins to handle Quick Navigation Button states */

@mixin quickNavBtnActive() {
    background-color: $quick-nav-active-color;
}

@mixin quickNavBtnInactive() {
    background-color: $quick-nav-color;
}


/*
 * ===== FADESHOW =====
 *
 * Base functionality for the fadeshow.
 * Do not change anything here unless you know what you are doing.
 */

[data-am-fadeshow] {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: $fade-color;

    /* Slides */
    .fs-slide {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        @include fadeshow-transition(opacity #{$fade-time}s ease);

        /* Display first child on load */
        &:first-child {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    /* Quick Navigation */
    .fs-quick-nav {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 15px;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        @include fadeshow-unselectable();
        @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(-50%));
    }

    .fs-quick-btn {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        @include fadeshow-transition(opacity 200ms ease);
        @include quickNavBtnInactive();

        &:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        /* Set active state to first button on load */
        &:first-child {
            @include quickNavBtnActive();
        }
    }

    /* Prev/Next Navigation */
    %prev-next {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: $prev-next-fontfamily;
        background-color: $prev-next-bg;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        @include fadeshow-transition(all 200ms ease);

        @if $responsive == true {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        &:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            font-size: $prev-next-icon-size;
            color: $prev-next-icon-color;
        }

        &:hover {
            background-color: $prev-next-bg-hover;
            @if $responsive == true {
                @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .fs-prev-btn {
        @extend %prev-next;
        left: 0;

        &:before {
            content: "#{$prev-icon}";
            left: 50%;
            @include fadeshow-transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
            @if $responsive == true {
                @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                    left: 30px;
                }
            }
        }

        @if $autohide-next-prev == true {
            @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(-100%));
            @if $responsive == true {
                @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                    @include fadeshow-transform(translate(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .fs-next-btn {
        @extend %prev-next;
        right: 0;

        &:before {
            content: "#{$next-icon}";
            right: 50%;
            @include fadeshow-transform(translate(50%, -50%));
            @if $responsive == true {
                @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                    right: 30px;
                }
            }
        }

        @if $autohide-next-prev == true {
            @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(100%));
            @if $responsive == true {
                @media (max-width: $breakpoint-small) {
                    @include fadeshow-transform(translate(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Base functionality */
    input[type="radio"] {
        position: fixed;
        top: -9999px;

        &:checked {

            /* This loop handles the slide switching and quick navigation active state */
            $i: $max-slides;

            @while $i > 0 {

                &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
                    /* Show slide */
                    ~ .fs-slides {
                        .fs-slide {
                            //Cancel autoplay
                            opacity: 0;
                            @include fadeshow-animation(none !important);
                        }
                        .fs-slide:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                            opacity: 1;
                        }
                    }

                    /* Add active state to dot */
                    ~ .fs-quick-nav {
                        .fs-quick-btn {
                            @include quickNavBtnInactive();
                            /* Cancel autoplay */
                            @include fadeshow-animation(none !important);
                        }
                        .fs-quick-btn:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                            background-color: $quick-nav-active-color;
                            &:hover {
                                opacity: 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                $i: $i - 1;
            }

            /* Hide navigation if only one slide */
            &:first-of-type:last-of-type {
                ~ .fs-quick-nav,
                ~ .fs-prev-nav,
                ~ .fs-next-nav {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /* Autohide Prev/Next Navigation */
    @if $autohide-next-prev == true {
        &:hover {
            .fs-prev-btn,
            .fs-next-btn {
                @include fadeshow-transform(translateX(0));
            }
        }
    }

}


/*
 * ===== PREV/NEXT NAVIGATION =====
 *
 * This section handles the prev/next navigation.
 */

/* Handle Prev/Next buttons */
[data-am-fadeshow~="next-prev-navigation"] {
    input[type="radio"] {

        &:checked {

            $i: $max-slides;

            @while $i > 0 {

                &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {

                    $prev: ($i - 1);
                    $next: ($i + 1);

                    /* Show previous button */
                    @if $prev > 0 {
                        ~ .fs-prev-nav {
                            .fs-prev-btn {
                                display: none;
                            }
                            .fs-prev-btn:nth-child(#{$prev}) {
                                display: block;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /* Show next button */
                    @if $next < ($max-slides + 1) {
                        ~ .fs-next-nav {
                            .fs-next-btn {
                                display: none;
                            }
                            .fs-next-btn:nth-child(#{$next}) {
                                display: block;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /* Show last prev button if first slide */
                    &:first-of-type {
                        ~ .fs-prev-nav {
                            .fs-prev-btn:last-child {
                                display: block;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /* Show first next button if last slide */
                    &:last-of-type {
                        ~ .fs-next-nav {
                            .fs-next-btn:first-child {
                                display: block;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
              $i: $i - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Display first pair of Prev/Next Buttons on load */
    .fs-prev-btn:last-child {
        display: block;
    }

    .fs-next-btn:nth-child(2) {
        display: block
    }

}


/*
 * ===== AUTOPLAY =====
 *
 * Functions to handle autoplay.
 * If you're not going to use autoplay, set $autoplay to false.
 * This part tends to compile into a lot of uneccesary CSS otherwise.
 */

@if $autoplay == true {

    $i: $max-slides;

    @while $i > 1 {

        $total-duration: $autoplay-duration * $i;

        @keyframes quickNavAnimation-#{$i} {
            0% { @include quickNavBtnInactive();  }
            #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
            #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { @include quickNavBtnActive(); }
            #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
            100% { @include quickNavBtnInactive(); }
        }
        @if $prefix == true {
            @-webkit-keyframes quickNavAnimation-#{$i} {
                0% { @include quickNavBtnInactive();  }
                #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
                #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { @include quickNavBtnActive(); }
                #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
                100% { @include quickNavBtnInactive(); }
            }
        }

        @keyframes slidesAnimation-#{$i} {
            0% { opacity: 0; }
            #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
            #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { opacity: 1; }
            #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
            100% { opacity: 0; }
        }
        @if $prefix == true {
            @-webkit-keyframes slidesAnimation-#{$i} {
                0% { opacity: 0; }
                #{100% * $fade-time / $total-duration},
                #{100% * $autoplay-duration / $total-duration} { opacity: 1; }
                #{100% * ($autoplay-duration + $fade-time) / $total-duration},
                100% { opacity: 0; }
            }
        }

        [data-am-fadeshow~="autoplay"] {
            input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(#{$i}):last-of-type {

                /* Slide animation */
                ~ .fs-slides {
                    .fs-slide {
                        @include fadeshow-animation(slidesAnimation-#{$i} #{$total-duration}s infinite);
                    }
                }

                /* Quick navigation animation */
                ~ .fs-quick-nav {
                    .fs-quick-btn {
                        @include fadeshow-animation(quickNavAnimation-#{$i} #{$total-duration}s infinite);
                    }
                }

                /* Animation Delay */
                @for $j from 1 through $i {
                    ~ .fs-slides .fs-slide:nth-child(#{$j}),
                    ~ .fs-quick-nav .fs-quick-btn:nth-child(#{$j}) {
                        $animation-delay: #{($j - 1) * ($autoplay-duration) - $fade-time}s;
                        @include fadeshow-animation-delay(#{$animation-delay});
                    }
                }

            }
            $i: $i - 1;
        }
    }
}

/* Base Styling */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

***code for two link codepen ( the bad/ my version )It's the same**

Comment: Sorry for my english i not speak this language , please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the styling is in SCSS instead of CSS. Convert the styling to css and include it in your pen or simply add the SCSS prerocessor in your pen

To compile to css in pen

[image]

Comment: how to convert in scss for my index file  ? i`m beginner :))

Comment: In fact you don't need that link. in your css box in your pen, click the down arrow and compile to css....

Comment: Added a picture on how to compile in pen